# How to remove html listbox border?

Tags: listbox

I am having a listbox and I want to remove its border. Can any one help?

I thought of using clip in jquery? Anyone knows that?please help

Comment: <select id="lbCommcatFrom" runat="server" style="height: 230px; width: 232px" multiple
                                                                                                                        name="lbCommcatFrom" class="ContentTextNormal">
                                                                                                                    </select>

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="lbCommcatFrom" runat="server" 
      style="height: 230px; width: 232px;  border: none;" 
      multiple name="lbCommcatFrom" class="ContentTextNormal">  
</select>
```

or set border color to transparent.
either in css border-color: transparent;

or in code behind something like

```
listbox.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```